# Why does my Node.js MS SQL script never end unless I CTRL+C out of it?

Tags: node.js, async-await, node-sqlserver

The `await` keyword can only be used inside an `async` function so I created a `main()` that is asynchronous and execute it at the global level. Everything runs correctly but then the program sits there in the event loop and never ends. I could add `process.exit()` but it seems heavy handed.

```js
const mssql = require('mssql');

;(async function main() {
    console.log("Started");
    try {
        await mssql.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_STRING);
        const result = await mssql.query`SELECT CHECKSUM('a')`;
        console.dir(result);
        console.log("Success!");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log("Failed!");
    }
    console.log("Finished");
})();
```

I assume this has to do with the `mssql` module peculiarities more than anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the connection closed automatically after a query or not?

If not I think the problem is that you need to close the connection and then it will end the process.

I hope this helped!

Comment: Oh geez, I feel foolish now. I added `await mssql.close()` and it ended gracefully. This would be good to add to the example on the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql